# Error using Slim framework and Twig template

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm trying to make Slim work with Twig template system, this is part of my `index.php`

```
// Twig [Template]
require 'Extras/Views/Twig.php';
TwigView::$twigDirectory = __DIR__ . '/vendor/Twig/lib/Twig/';

//Slim
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => $twigView
));
```

And this is my structure

```
Extras
    |_Views
        |_Twig.php
Slim
templates
vendor
    |_Twig
        |_lib
            |_Twig
index.php
```

I try several times with other configurations and searching buy I  ALLWAYS get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Slim\View' not found in C:\wamp\www\slim\Extras\Views\Twig.php on line 43
```

Can anyone help me here? All the examples I had found was using composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solve it.
This is the solution:

```
// Slim PHP
require "Slim/Slim.php";
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

// Twig
require "Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// Start Slim.
/** @var $app Slim */
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    "view" => new \Slim\Extras\Views\Twig()
));
```

And this is my structure now.

```
Slim
|_Extras
    |_Views
        |_Twig.php
|_Slim
templates
Twig
 |_lib
   |_Twig
      |_Autoloader.php
index.php
```

¡I hope this help someone else!

Comment: your problem already solved...:) i'm sory for late response , i'm very busy so i can't see your request on my blog indoallcode.com

Comment: Just what I needed, now I'm wondering how I'll go about setting the template directory, or if I'll need to or where it defaults to.

Comment: @CTS_AE maybe you should ask a new question, but try this: 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html
`require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));`

Comment: @gonzalon I wanted to edit my last comment but couldn't, guess I just had to double post? I did find out the answer though when initializing Slim pass in `'templates.path' => '../private/templates/'` It's in the slim documentation if you search for templates.path

Answer (score 2):

Now Slim-Extras is DEPRECATED, we must use Slim-Views (https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Views):

```
require "Slim/Slim.php";
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$slim = new \Slim\Slim( array(
        'debug' => false, 
        'templates.path' => 'fooDirTemplates', 
        'view' => '\Slim\Views\Twig'
    ));

$twigView = $slim->view();
$twigView->parserOptions = array(
        'debug' => false
    );
$twigView->parserDirectory = 'Twig';
$twigView->parserExtensions = array(
        '\Slim\Views\TwigExtension'
    );

$slim->notFound( 'fooNotFoundFunction' );
$slim->error( 'fooErrorFunction' );

// SLIM routes...

$slim->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still running in to this issue.
The problem for me was that I had installed both slim/views AND slim/twig-view.
I uninstalled slim/views and it worked

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer little bit more, for fellow programmers, to understand how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: I believe this is a clash of namespaces - both packages `slim/views` and `slim/twig-view` on packagist offer the class `\Slim\Views\Twig`, so you cannot use both packages at the same time without some inconsistencies. The package `slim\views` supports both Twig and Smarty, and is better supported, being an "official" slim package. Composer does not care if two packages have the same namespaced classes - it will just use whichever it finds first without complaint, and you can end up with a hybrid of multiple packages if you are not careful.

Comment: @Beanz - this was the issue for me, too. It wasn't clear from the various places I was reading about slim and twig together, but when I *added* slim/twig-view and removed slim/views, it works.